# Limit number of prompted arguments

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I want to prompt the user to input just two numbers which represent the size NxN of a board. If the user write less than 1 or more than 2 numbers, the program don't allow him to do that and instead, handle this by an exception.

For example:

```
public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Board size NxN: ");

    int width = userInput.nextInt();
    int height = userInput.nextInt();
}
}
```

How can achieve this using a try-catch block limiting the user to input only 2 numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class Tester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Board size NxN: ");
    try {
        int width = userInput.nextInt();
        int height = userInput.nextInt();
        if (userInput.hasNext()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.err.println("Enter just two numbers");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When I enter the first number, then the second one, I press enter and it continues to wait for a third number. When the third number is put, then it throws the exception: Board size NxN: 2 3
8
"Enter just two numbers"

Comment: This is logical. You need to present prompts to user like 'Enter 1st', 'Enter 2nd', 'Correct (y/n)?', and accept only 'YyNn' as input to last one (and only numbers to first ones).